# Is is lawful to install a hidden camera on my car?

Tags: vehicle, evidence

I have a terrible neighbor, whom, [among the litany of other offenses](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/15042/what-legal-course-is-there-with-a-bad-neighbor), I suspect of putting nails in my car tires.

I approached my apartment management about installing a hidden camera, and they responded essentially by saying, "We can't give permission, but we can't say no. Good luck catching him, not that we condone it."

Is it lawful to install a hidden camera on my car with the intent to use footage/images as evidence to give the police or use in court?

Comment: For this question, the location is most important - this is legal in some places and illegal in others.

Comment: Which jurisdiction?

Comment: OP's profile states Austin, TX, USA.

Answer (score 2):

It is legal to install a camera on your car. It is legal to film anyone using this camera provided:

- you have the permission (implicit or explicit) of the person in control of the premises
- the person being filmed does not have a reasonable expectation of privacy
- you do not use the images for commercial purposes without permission of the "model"

There are many questions on this site that address photos.

Comment: As long as it's not in Sweden.

Comment: And if it's not in Germany.

Comment: and its not france

Answer (score 1):

As Dale M [answered](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/15043/333) to your other question,

> This is a crime. If you can get evidence to prove it then you can report him to the police and/or sue him for the damage.

But actually, *you don't need evidence that this person committed the crime to report it to the police.*

So report the crime to the police.  They may investigate, although it may not be likely in many jurisdictions, and if they do, they may identify the perpetrator.  If they do not investigate, they may be able to advise you on whether you can put surveillance on your own vehicle.